# Not getting connection after 8 hrs in Hibernate 3.0

Tags: web, database-connection, hibernate3

I have configured my hibenate.config.xml like this...But after some hours not getting the DB connection ...In MYSQL the wait-timeout is default 28800 or 8 hrs..and here it is less than that. No clue about it.

```
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://11.243.188.53/XXX</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">admin</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password1$</property>
    <!-- Set AutoCommit to true -->
    <property name="connection.autocommit"> false </property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- SQL Dialect to use. Dialects are database specific -->
    <property name="dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>




      <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxActive">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxWait">-1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.whenExhaustedAction">2</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.testOnBorrow">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.testOnReturn">true</property>
         <property name="hibernate.dbcp.validationQuery">SELECT 1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.testWhileIdle">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.ps.maxActive">8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.ps.maxIdle">8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.ps.maxWait">60</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.ps.whenExhaustedAction">1</property>



       <!-- Disable second-level cache. -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="cache.use_minimal_puts">false</property>
    <property name="max_fetch_depth">3</property>
```

Still after some hours i am not able get the db connection.

Please help me out ..

Find the error log..

```
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2214)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2095)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2090)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:388)
        at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
        at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
        at com.cts.bfstools.batch.admin.LoginAction.getUserData(LoginAction.java:365)
        at com.cts.bfstools.batch.admin.LoginAction.getTenantList(LoginAction.java:168)
        at com.cts.bfstools.batch.admin.LoginAction.populate(LoginAction.java:156)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at  com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:270)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.cts.bfsibp.twalk.action.CustomInterceptor.intercept(CustomInterceptor.java:38)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.cts.bfsibp.twalk.action.TwalkFilter.doFilter(TwalkFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 250,154 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2916)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3459)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2107)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2648)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2086)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2237)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1778)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2211)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2475)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2927)
    ... 91 more
```

one more log :

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3272)
    ... 89 more

Comment: Where is the error statck trace ? "not getting the DB connection" simply won't be helpful.

Comment: added the error log pls have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

there is a possibility that you may not be releasing the hibernate session after your done with it.. try using the `OpenSessionInViewFilter`, avoid using `factory.openSession()`

I had faced similar issues in one of the projects i'm working on.. 
It would be very helpful if you can post the stacktrace before I can be sure of the cause.

Comment: can you check if your exception matches http://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-2769 or https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=943079&p=2440195#p2440195  since there are 2 reasons for the exception.

Comment: seems to be that only..but maxwait is set to -1 in my hibernate.config.xml

Comment: what do i need to do? I have same settings in hibernate config

Comment: check the version of the mysqljdbc. get the latest from mysql site and try again.

Comment: Disable query cache by setting "query_cache_size=0" in your my.cnf (in mysql), if it fails try Changing your streaming queries so that it includes the `SQL_NO_CACHE` flag. with the flag the query should look somethig like `select SQL_NO_CACHE * from tableName` .. this happens due to a corrupted query cache in the mysql.

Comment: thanks for your support...i used c2p0 its working fine...thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
```

OR

```
            <prop key="hibernate.dbcp.validationQuery">select 1</prop> 
            <prop key="hibernate.dbcp.testOnReturn">true</prop>
```

Add property in database Connection bean in xml

The above will test connections every time you borrow from the pool.